# Changing the system path variable is not saving the new path

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, path, jdk

I have just installed JDK (Windows 8 x64), when I run `java` in a `cmd` window all is fine, but when I run `javac` it gives an error message.

I have found that when I use `echo %PATH%` it shows the path as a different one leading to the JRE file instead.

1. I have input/added `jdk\bin;` to the path in system variables.
2. `javac` not recognised
3. `echo %PATH%` reveals that the path added is `JRE\bin;` which has no javac within and therefore the error message.
4. I go back to the variable editor and it shows the correct path `JDK\bin;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Enviroment variable editor is not saving new path

You need to start a new `cmd` prompt.

- Changes to environment variables made via the Control Panel do not affect any currently open `cmd` windows.
- You need to close them and open new ones.

---

#### How do I set or change the PATH system variable?

**Windows 8**

1. Drag the Mouse pointer to the Right bottom corner of the screen.
2. Click on the Search icon and type: "Control Panel".
3. Click "Control Panel" > "System" > "Advanced".
4. Click "Environment Variables", under "System Variables".
5. Click "PATH" (scroll to find it).
6. In the Edit window, modify PATH by adding the location of `javac` to the value for PATH.
7. Close the window.
8. Open a new `cmd` window.
9. Compile your Java program.

Source [How do I set or change the PATH system variable?](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)